# Best approach to creating a report generator

Tags: usability, forms, web-app, feedback

I'm working on improving an application that provides users with data metrics via tables and allows them to generate reports of the data metrics. The current implementation is that, depending on what report the users desire, they would need to navigate to different levels of the application in order to download it (e.g., if the user wants a company report, the user would have to navigate to the company level page to download it). One can imagine how tedious this process would be if the user wants different reports, and they would have to navigate through all the levels (Home > Company > Market > City).

My "solution" to this problem is an all-in-one report generator. As stated in the wireframe, dropdowns will disable/enable depending on the selection the users choose. Please refer to the wireframe for details descriptions.

I have tested this with a few users, and after playing around with it for a bit, they seem to prefer this method over the current implementation (download buttons scattered around the different levels). However, I'm wondering if there's a more efficient approach that wouldn't require for users to play around first before understanding the process.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not really. If you got your users to actually play around with your application you've come a long way. This is what users do when they see something new. This is true on iPhone, Facebook and any other device/application. Getting users to play is to me the gold medal!